# Sharing OAuth2 tokens between providers

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around a rather complex OAuth2 use case. I have two servers, one is a client side web server, which serves a website, the other is an API server, which is used to interface with all our backend data.

Currently users use a basic [UserCredentials](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/grant-types/user-credentials/) flow which creates an access token on our API server, which is then used to sign all requests from the webserver to the API

Is there a way I can allow users to log in using Google or Facebook, and either use the access token generated to sign API requests in the same way as above, or alternatively create an access token on our API which is then used the same way as above?

Answer (score 0):

In a word:  NO.

Let me try and explain why.   Lets start by looking at Google,  to access google you need to register your application in Google Apis console.  When you ask a user to give you access to there google data you do it using the client id and secret you got from apis console.  Then google goes about createing `your application` an access token for `there api` this info is all stored on there servers.     When you then try and use that access token they know which user gave you access to there data via the api.

Now the same holds true for Facebook, and your service as well.   They are all diffrent APIs offered by diffrent companys.  They create the Access tokens Google cant create you an access token to access data on Facebook any more then Facebook could to Google. Things just dont work that way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't really need to fetch data from those providers, I just need to use them to authenticate a user. I guess I would still need some way to map say a Google user to a user on my API :?

Comment: You just want to let users log into your site using There google or facebook acounts?

Comment: It's more like I need a way to allow users to log in to the API using Facebook/Google

Comment: Yes but to log into the API you need an application registered in Google apis console.  So it is your app they are using to access the API.

Comment: DaImTo, I think you are confusing chillievodka's own API server with the Google API. He has no need for the Google API, he just wants to let people authenticated as Google users access his web server and API, if I understand correctly.